# PHP $.row error when adding to function

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am very new at this, I am currently working on a PHP project and I have a calculation for age on it, all of that seems to be working fine.  The only problem is that I cannot get the age calculating row to format itself as `$.row` without getting an error.  So what I am currently getting is a table that is missing the first row of age calculation.

Here is the code I am currently working with.

```
 Print "<tr>";          
Print '<td><a href="cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=' . $row['PlayerID'] .             '"           style="text-decoration:none;">' . $row['FullName'] .             '</a></td>';      
Print "<td><center>".$row['CNGHLRights']."</centre></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['Season']."</center></td> ";
    $DOB = $row[DOB]; //dd.mm.yyyy
Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y;"</center></td>";
$user_date = new DateTime($DOB);
$curr_date = new DateTime();
$age_cal = $curr_date->diff($user_date);
Print "<td><center>".$row['ContractL']."</centre></td> ";
Print "<td><center>".$row['ContractM']."</centre></td> ";}
```

The problem is around `Print "<td><center>".$age_cal` I cannot put a `.$row` in front of it.

Here is the site that I am working with so you can see the problem I am getting.

http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/contract.php?CNGHLID=1&ContractID=1&Season=15

The error I get is the column returns "array" all the way down it and that is when I enter this

```
  Print "<td><center>".$row.$age_cal->y;"</center></td>";
```

Comment: Also post the code line which generates the error

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I added it to the original post. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the value of `$age_cal->y` and what is its relation with `$row`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky the $age_cal->y pulls information from another element DOB and calculates the age of the person giving me a number.

Comment: But $row is an array and you cant echo an whole array in one line in concatenation with a string. Do you mean `$row[$age_cal->y]` ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky when I put in Print "<td><center>".$row[$age_cal->y]; it returns me with nothing but blank results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after the discussion it appears that the only thing you are missing is a period `.`

```
Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y;"</center></td>";
```

Should be

```
Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y."</center></td>";
                                ^
```

Secondly the reason you are not getting the first age is that you are displaying age before calculating it! So it works only second time onwards

```
Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y;"</center></td>";   // Display first, calculate later?
$user_date = new DateTime($DOB);
$curr_date = new DateTime();
$age_cal = $curr_date->diff($user_date);
```

This should be like:

```
$user_date = new DateTime($DOB);
$curr_date = new DateTime();
$age_cal = $curr_date->diff($user_date);
Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y."</center></td>";
```

Comment: The Results are still not matching up http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/contract.php?CNGHLID=1&ContractID=1&Season=15 the ages are not matching the proper person as well. I am missing the top result for age and the second one on the list corresponds to the top person.

Comment: Yep see the updated answer, The second issue that I referred is the actual problem

Comment: I am still getting the same problem as before. Even with the fix.

Comment: Print "<td><center>".$age_cal->y."</center></td>";
 $user_date = new DateTime($DOB);
 $curr_date = new DateTime();

Comment: Did you apply the second fix? Can you update your code in question so I can see

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I feel pretty dumb for making that mistake. Thanks again for your patience.